# Litecoin Core wallet.dat

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin, wallet.dat, wallet-recovery

I am trying to recover my old LTC account. I still have the address (on blockchain I can still see the correct amount of LTC) and I still hold the old wallet.dat file, which I saved in the past.

I've downloaded LTC core in order to make a few transactions, but obviously I couldnt see the LTC balance. I've checked out this website and read I had to replace the wallet.dat file by the old wallet.dat file, which I did. Restarted LTC Core, but still can not see anything.

The synchronising seems to be up to date though.

What to do?

Many thanks!!

Comment: OK. I've just managed to solve the issue.

Comment: It appears I also had to rescan.

"C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\litecoin-qt.exe" -rescan

So for all those in the near future encountering the same prob as me; these were the steps I had to follow:

- download LiteCore
- synch (which took me 3 days)
- replaced new wallet.dat by old wallet.dat
- run -rescan as per above

Comment: Thanks Fred for answering your own question. Could you please post it as an answer instead of a comment? :)